# does rsync switch -a (ARCHIVE) always includes -l (symlinks)

Tags: rsync, symlink, archive

does rsync option `-a` (ARCHIVE) always includes `-l` (symlinks) in linux systems?

I was revising some old scripts containing both options and thought to drop unneeded options. The script might be used by other people or system, so I'd like to double check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `man rsync` it does:

> -a            archive mode is -rlptgoD (no -A,-X,-U,-N,-H)

So you do not need `-l` if you're using `-a`.
It's always been like that, one can view the source code (including the man pages for all revisions) here: https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/src/

Comment: thanks, yet I assume it is for some recent version of rsync, could be different for some earlier release?

Comment: @Serge read `man rsync` on your system and you'll have a definitive answer

Comment: unfortunately I expect other people to use my script, I do not have access to their command line

Comment: Thanks @don_crissti , btw do you have a prooflink?

Comment: @don_crissti thanks, indeed in main.c at line 303 `fprintf(stderr,"-a       : archive mode (same as -rlptDog)\n")` if you like an up-vote, add the answer